# labeling points on the chart - matlab

Tags: matlab

Goodnight.
How can I label the graph points with bits?
This is my code:

```
  L = 1e4;
    SNRdB = 0:28;
    SNR = 10.^(SNRdB/10); 
    r = 10.^(SNRdB/10);
    alpha = 0.3;


    % Número máximo de iterações para um único SNR
    max_run = 100;


    for sk = 1:length(SNRdB)
        
        for tk = 1:max_run
            
            % 1 ou -1 para sinal em fase (an)
            x_inp_I = sign(rand(1,L)- 0.5);
         
  

      % 1 ou -1 para sinal de quadratura (bn)
        x_inp_Q = sign(rand(1,L)- 0.5);
        
        QPSK = x_inp_I + 1i .* x_inp_Q;
                 
        % Gera bits de marca d'água aleatórios (dI)
        Bit_wat_I = sign(rand(1,L)- 0.5);
        
        % Gera bits de marca d'água aleatórios (dQ)
        Bit_wat_Q = sign(rand(1,L)- 0.5); 
        
        
        % encontrar a equação
        for k = 1:L 
    
    if Bit_wat_I(k) == 1  &&  Bit_wat_Q(k) == 1     
        
Bit_enviado(k) = (x_inp_I(k) .* ((sqrt(1-alpha)) + (sqrt(alpha)))) + (1i .* x_inp_Q(k) * (sqrt(1-alpha)) + (sqrt(alpha))));  
                      
                end             
                 
            end
            
        end
    end
```

The plot got this way:

[image]

I would like to label it this way:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code will generate a similar figure to your second image

```
rM = [-3 -1 1 3];
strLabel = dec2bin(0:15);

figure
set(gcf, 'Color', 'White')
hold on
nInc = 1;
for nX = rM
    for nY = rM
        plot(nX, nY, 'b+')
        text(nX, nY-0.3, strLabel(nInc,:), ...
                'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center')
        nInc = nInc + 1;
    end
end
xlabel('In-Phase')
ylabel('Quadrature')
title('Scatter plot')
set(gca, 'XTick', -4:4)
set(gca, 'YTick', -4:4)
axis([-4 4 -4 4])
axis square
grid off
box on
```

Comment: Vote up my answer please ! thank you ... btw usually for such plot the results of the decoding provide a cloud point around the ground truth for the 16 values 0000 to 1111.